# jQuery bubble sort не получается сделать анимацию

Tags: javascript, jquery, сортировка, анимация

Доброго времени суток. Не получается корректно заставить работать анимацию сортировки. 
На данном этапе перестал добавлять элементы в DOM

```js
function getRandomArray() {
  var a = [];

  function getRandom() {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a.push(getRandom());
  };
  return a
};

function bubbleSortAnimation(list) {
  var animSteps = [];

  function printArray(list) {
    var str = [],
      i = 0,
      l = list.length
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
      str.push('<li>' + list[i] + '</li>')
    };
    $('#not-sorted').html(str.join(''));
  };

  function setSwap(list, itemFist, itemSecond) {
    var tmp = list[itemFist];
    list[itemFist] = list[itemSecond];
    list[itemSecond] = tmp;
    animSteps.push(function() {
        $('#not-sorted').children('li').eq(itemFist).add($('#not-sorted').children('li').eq(itemSecond)).addClass('highlight');
      },
      function() {
        var tmp = $('#not-sorted').children('li').eq(itemFist).text();
        $('#not-sorted').children('li').eq(itemFist).text($('#not-sorted').children('li').eq(itemSecond).text());
        $('#not-sorted').children('li').eq(itemSecond).text(tmp);
      }, function() {
        $('#not-sorted').children('li').eq(itemFist).add($('#not-sorted').children('li').eq(itemSecond)).removeClass('highlight');
      });
  };

  function animation() {
    if (animSteps.length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        animSteps.splice(0, 1)[0]();
        animation();
      }, 500);
    }
  };

  function sort(list) {
    for (var j = list.lenght; j > 1; --j) {
      for (var i = 0; i < j - 1; i++) {
        if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
          setSwap(list, i, i + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```